# Moving Background of a View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a really large image that I want to use as a background image of a view. However, I don't want to display the entire image at once; I want only a part of the image to be displayed, and then I want to animate it to display other parts of it, similar to the "infinite background" in games (only not infinite in my case ;)). 
What is the best way to do this? Will I have to separate the image in several pieces and then somehow animate the transition between the pieces, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. This piece of code does the magic:

```
self.backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];
self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
self.backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
[self.view addSubview: self.backgroundImageView];
```

The key was setting the contentMode to UIViewContentModeBottomLeft.

Answer (score 2):

How about having `UIScrollView` as a background view? You can then put `UIImageView` inside that scroll view and control scroll view's `contentOffset` as needed.

Comment: If I use UIScrollView and add a UIImageView inside it, the image is shrinked to the size of the screen. The image size 640 x 6298. What I want to achieve is that I have only a bottom part of the image displayed (only as much as it fits on the screen) and then animate it so that the image is from the bottom to top. I don't see how to display only one portion of the image without cropping it.

Comment: The image won't be shrunk if you set up scroll view correctly (proper `contentSize` and `scale`). Also make sure the size of your image view is right (`initWithImage:` should do the job).

Comment: Found a simpler way to do it. See the answer below. But thx anyway :)